# Subtract two shamsi dates in type script

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to subtract two dates
I get one from the api
One too:

```
var eventStartTime = new Date (). toLocaleDateString ('fa-IR'). replace (/ ([0-9]) / g, token => String.fromCharCode (token.charCodeAt (0) - 1728));
```

Today's date

Now I want to reduce them and get the age

Here it becomes a string because of `tolocalDateString`

And I also use `.valueof()` again as a string and I can not subtract them

my code:

```
  let arr;

    this.formsService.get_date_duration().subscribe(res => {
      arr = res

      var eventStartTime = new Date().toLocaleDateString('fa-IR').replace(/([۰-۹])/g, token => String.fromCharCode(token.charCodeAt(0) - 1728));


      eventStartTime = eventStartTime.valueOf();

      var eventEndTime = new Date(arr).valueOf();

      var duration = eventStartTime - eventEndTime;


      console.log("duration", duration)
    }
    )
```

Comment: why don't you use https://www.npmjs.com/package/jalali-moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) or [jalali-moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jalali-moment) with this function:

```
const a = '2022-01-09';
const b = '2022-01-08';
moment(a, 'YYYY/MM/DD').diff(moment(b, 'YYYY/MM/DD'), 'days');
```

If You are using **jalali-moment** and your input date is in jalali format you have to use it like:

```
const a = '1400-10-19';
const b = '1400-10-18';
moment(a, 'jYYYY/jMM/jDD').diff(moment(b, 'jYYYY/jMM/jDD'), 'days');
```

It will return difference in **days** for other types of results like minutes, hours,... see [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/).

You can also use functions like `isBefore` or `isAfter`.

```
moment('2010-10-20').isBefore('2010-12-31', 'year'); // false
moment('2010-10-20').isBefore('2011-01-01', 'year'); // true
```

In jalali:

```
moment('1400-10-19', 'jYYYY-jMM-jDD').isBefore('1400-10-18', 'jYYYY-jMM-jDD'); // false
moment('1400-10-19', 'jYYYY-jMM-jDD').isBefore('1400-10-20', 'jYYYY-jMM-jDD'); // true
```